# Keeping HTML files separated from the PHP files (template based)

Tags: php, templates

I am trying to keep all the PHP files **separated** from the HTML files. Sort of a template based project but *without using any template engines* as they are mostly bloated and the fact that you will need to learn another language which is not PHP at all.

Anyway, I have the following code in my `index.php` file:

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT id FROM products ORDER by id";

$product_list = "";
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($db_conx, $query)) {

    /* execute statement */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    /* bind result variables */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id);

    /* fetch values */
    while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
        $product_list .= "

}
}

?>
<?php include "template.php"; ?>
```

And I have this code in my `template.php` file:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

<div class='prod_box'>
        <div class='center_prod_box'>
          <div class='product_title'><a href='#'>$product_name</a></div>
          <div class='product_img'><a href='#'><img src='images/" . $id . "Image1.jpg' alt='' border='0' /></a></div>
          <div class='prod_price'><span class='reduce'>350$</span> <span class='price'>270$</span></div>
        </div>
        <div class='prod_details_tab'> <a href='#' class='prod_buy'>Add to Cart</a> <a href='#' class='prod_details'>Details</a> </div>
      </div>

</body>
</html>
```

When I run the code, I basically get the HTML page displayed exactly as you see it above. So no data is being shown from the MySQL database!

**EDIT:**

I tried using the following code in my `while` loop and still the same:

```
$id = $row["id"];
$product_name = $row["product_name"];
$price = $row["price"];
$shipping = $row["shipping"];
$category = $row["category"];
```

Could someone please help me out with this?

Comment: Where did you define `$product_name`? `$product_name` is also not between php tags.

Comment: @Daan, I thought, i don't need to do that because I am using the `while loop`. so everything should be pulled from the mysql database in the `while loop`.

Comment: Instead of reinventing the wheel, have a look at [Mustache](http://mustache.github.io) / [MustachePHP](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php).

Comment: @user3592614 Search for MVC

Comment: @Thorsten, re-inventing the wheel?1 PHP is a template programming language so i'm afraid to say but any other template engines like smarty, MVC, twig, etc etc are just unnecessary and useless.

Comment: Template engines do not necessarily force you to learn a templating language - some of them use PHP. I wrote [my own](https://github.com/halfer/TemplateSystem) primarily for WordPress, but it's small and works well with non-WP use-cases.

Comment: @user3592614 `MVC` is a design pattern not a product.

Comment: Seriously, listen to @LozCherone and me, and use (H)MVC and a proper template engine (i recommend mustache). they are useful and keep your code clean.

Comment: And for your question: @Daan answered it, you need to set your `$product_name` in PHP tags in `template.php`: `<?php echo $product_name; ?>` or use short tags, if available on your system.

Comment: @Thorsten, my aim is to keep away from `echo this` or `echo that` in my template file.

Comment: @user3592614 How is your variables content supposed to be printed on your screen without the use of screen-printing methods? Sounds like even more re-invention of even more wheels... Seriously, how much (PHP) coding experience do you have?

Comment: @Thorsten, Seriously, how much (PHP) coding experience do you have? not a much as you mate. anyway, I was just having banter with you guys...

Comment: @user3592614 http://codeangel.org/articles/simple-php-template-engine.html

Answer (score -7, accepted):

You need to use the [`extract()`](http://php.net/extract) function in PHP to get this sorted out. It will then start working as a Controller - View architecture that you are looking for.

For example:

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT id FROM products ORDER by id";
$product_list = "";

if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($db_conx, $query)) {

    /* execute statement */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    /* bind result variables */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id);

    /* fetch values */
    while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
        $product_list .= "";
    }
}

$data['product_list'] = $product_list;
$view = 'template.php';
loadTemplate($view, $data);

function loadTemplate($view, $data)
{
    extract($data);
    include($template);
}

?>
```

Then directly use `$product_list` in the view section. This should do it.

Working example:

```
<?php
    $data['test'] = 'This is a working example';
    $view = 'workingExampleView.php';
    loadTemplate($view,$data);

function loadTemplate($viewName,$viewData)
{
    extract($viewData);
    include($viewName);
}
?>
```

Create a new File naming it workingExampleView.php:

```
<html>
<body>
    <span><?php echo $test; ?></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This will return an empty `$product_list`... How can this be the solution? Not ment in an offensive way :) Just curious..

Comment: The indentation could do with a bit of fixing too - would you tweak?

Comment: Please elaborate what is it that you guys did not understood.What the extract function does is what is in the key part of an array converts it into an individual variable as simple as that.It is just the matter that whats coming from the query should be correctly taken into the variable.Supposedly this is how the M-V-C architecture works.

Comment: Why dont you guys implement it and then have your very own thoughts.And we are not here to fight but get things sorted out.

Comment: @JigneshRawal it's not about the extract function, it's about you're extracting nothing at all with empty input...

Comment: Ok i guess i will have to get you guys a working example.Please see the next answer

Comment: @JigneshRawal MVC is a pattern is a specific set of constraints that describes information flow between several application layer. It has **nothing** to do with templating. And if you think, that "view" and "template" is the same thing, you do not have a slightest clue about how to implement MVC.

Comment: My friend i did not mean that what i am saying is MVC.I just meant that this is one way by which data can pass between controllers and view.

Comment: @JigneshRawal in MVC, controllers **do not** pass data to views.

Comment: @tereško I have been using code igniter since quite a long time for now.I request you to do one thing is download a copy and in any of your editors search for the keyword extract.I hope you will see a lot of it .

Comment: Yep thanks i am too clueless on where this discussion is going.Take Care

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest using a template system to parse your template file.

Just something quick and dirty:

```
class Example {
    // This will be used to save all the variables set trough the set() function within the class as an array
    private $variables = array();

    function set($name,$value) {
                // Here we are going to put the key and value in the variables array
        $this->variables[$name] = $value;
    }

    function Template($file) {
        // First set the file path of the template, the filename comes from the Template({filename}) function.
        $file = '/templates/'.$file.'.php';

        // Here we are going to extract our array, every key will be a variable from here!
        extract($this->variables);

        // Check if it is actually a file
        if (!is_file($file)) {
            throw new Exception("$file not found");
        // Check if the file is readable
        } elseif(!is_readable($file)) {
            throw new Exception("No access to $file");
        } else {
        // if both are fine we are going to include the template file :)
            include($file);
        }
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
$class = new Example;
$class->set("data", $data);
// like passing a name:
$class->set("user", $username);
$class->Template("filename");
```

Then in your template file you can use `$data` and `$user` with their contents.

Also, in your template file you're not displaying the variable because it's not in between of PHP tags. Here's two examples for you, one short and the other in the normal format:

```
<?=$productname?>
// or :
<?php echo $productname; ?>
```

Oh, and you actually do nothing here:

```
while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
        $product_list .= "

}
}
```

You NEED to close the opening `"` with `";` and nothing is added to `$product_list`.

Comment: sorry mate that doesn't make sense at all!

Comment: This code is just allowing PHP to parse the HTML file and replace the variables with real data that you have used $class->set on. A basic good example to answer the question. If @user3592614 doesn't understand, then he should look at some tutorials to get a better understanding how templating works as this is not something PHP was designed to do out of the box.

Comment: @JoranDenHouting: can we do this thing directly by the DEFINE key word or not?

Comment: OK, I think we all know who are the ones being rude here. This is the second time I've had to remove comments. Please stop.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, you should use a **template system**. If you don't want to hinder with learning how they work, there is a very easy approach: create a very simple one yourself. You'll need it sooner or later. The below solution should be very easy, and it's copy-pasteable.

The basic operation of such system is that you:

1. **Load** the template file with placeholder strings.
2. **Process** the template file (replace placeholders with actual values).
3. **Output** (or return) the HTML with now processed text.

An example class that is very easy to comprehend might be this:

```
class HtmlPage
{
    private $html;

    # Loads specified template file into $html
    public function Load($template)
    {
        if (!file_exists($template)) {
            echo "Specified template ($template) does not exist.";
            return false;
        }

        $this->html = file_get_contents($template);
        return true;
    }

    # Takes in an array of data, key is the placeholder replaced, value is the new text
    public function Process($data_array)
    {
        if (!is_array($data_array)) return;

        foreach ($data_array as $search => $replace)
        {
            # Add brackets so they don't have to be manually typed out when calling HtmlPage::Process()
            $search = "{$search}";

            $this->html = str_replace($search, $replace, $this->html);
        }
    }

    # Returns the page
    public function GetHtml()
    {
        return $this->html;
    }
}
```

Can be used as:

```
$page_title = "My fancy page title";
$page_text  = "All your base are belong to us.";

$page = new HtmlPage();

$page->Load('html/templates/mypage.html');
$page->Process(array(
    'TITLE' => $page_title,
    'TEXT' => $page_text
));
echo $page->GetHtml();
```

The above code will replace

```
<html>
    <head>
        {TITLE}
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>{TEXT}</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

...to...

```
<html>
    <head>
        My fancy page title
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>All your base are belong to us.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

In your case, this will work like the following:

html/templates/product-item.html:

```
<div class='prod_box'>
    <div class='center_prod_box'>
        <div class='product_title'>
            <a href='#'>{PRODUCT_NAME}</a>
        </div>

        <div class='product_img'>
            <a href='#'><img src='images/{PRODUCT_ID}/Image1.jpg' alt='' border='0' /></a>
        </div>

        <div class='prod_price'>
            <span class='reduce'>{PRODUCT_PRICE_REDUCE}</span> <span class='price'>{PRODUCT_PRICE}</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class='prod_details_tab'>
        <a href='#' class='prod_buy'>Add to Cart</a> <a href='#' class='prod_details'>Details</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT * FROM products ORDER by id";

$product_list = "";

if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($db_conx, $query))
{
    /* execute statement */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    /* bind result variables */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id);

    /* fetch values */
    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    while ($product = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $product_html = new HtmlPage();
        $product_html->Load('html/templates/product-list.html');
        $product_html->Process(array(
            'PRODUCT_NAME' => $product['name'];
            'PRODUCT_ID' => $product['id'];
            'PRODUCT_PRICE' => $product['price'];
            'PRODUCT_PRICE_REDUCE' => $product['price_reduce'];
        ));
        $product_list .= $product_html->GetHtml();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit of a mess, you need to go back to the basics: your statement is returning `$id` and not `$product` as you mentioned. To return anything from the database, in your `template.html` do:

```
<html>
    <body>

        <!-- More html here ... -->

        <div class='product_title'>
            <!-- Return value like this -->
            <a href='#'><?php echo $product_name; ?></a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Make sure you check the value exists first.

Answer (score 0):

In index.php

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT id FROM products ORDER by id";

$product_list = "";
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($db_conx, $query)) {

    /* execute statement */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    /* bind result variables */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id);

    /* fetch values */

}

define("PRODUCT_NAME",$row["product_name"]);
define("PRODUCT_ID",$row["id"]);
define("PRODUCT_PRICE",$row["price"]);
define("PRODUCT_SHIPPING",$row["shipping"]);
define("PRODUCT_CATEGORY",$row["category"]);
?>
<?php include "template.php"; ?>
```

and in template.php

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

<div class='prod_box'>
    <div class='center_prod_box'>
      <div class='product_title'><a href='#'><?=PRODUCT_NAME?></a></div>
      <div class='product_img'><a href='#'><img src='images/<?=PRODUCT_ID?>/Image1.jpg' alt='' border='0' /></a></div>
      <div class='prod_price'><span class='reduce'>350$</span> <span class='price'>270$</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class='prod_details_tab'> <a href='#' class='prod_buy'>Add to Cart</a> <a href='#' class='prod_details'>Details</a> </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `$product_list .= "` in the loop seems to be missing some code?

Comment: The `define` functions should be in the `while()` function, also remove the `$product_list` line and you're there :)

Comment: @JoranDenHouting: i am felling like a stupid because your answer is much much better that my answer ......Thanks for that

Comment: You shouldn't, everyone has their own coding style and ways of reaching the same result. :)

Comment: @VishalSharma, How do you get all the data from the from the database? for example: this way we're only getting the first item in the mysql database. what if we want to get all of the items and display them in the template page?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but now `$row` doesn't come from anywhere. I'd advise against `define` here too - it feels wrong, since `define` is intended for static information that does not change across an application. If you end up putting it in a loop, you'll get an error, since constants cannot be redefined.