# Separate HTML and PHP files

Tags: php, html, web

I am currently working on a software project for school using *PHP*, *HTML*, and *CSS*. All the examples I find online display the *PHP* and *HTML* in the same file.
I know that there are advance frameworks that allow me to decouple the *PHP* and *HTML* but I am looking for a simple and easy way to focus the responsibilities of the two independently.

**How can I separate my HTML and PHP without the use of a framework?**

Comment: This has been answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23407242/keeping-html-files-separated-from-the-php-files-template-based?rq=1

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried by yourself.

Comment: It sounds like you are talking about a Templating engine rather than a Framework. Be careful about re-inventing this particular Wheel, it may be better to go with one that has already been written rather than write a poor equivalent of the many sizes and shapes of existing Wheels already available.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand **why** you think this is beneficial to you, but you could separate your HTML and PHP into two files and then require the HTML into your PHP file when neccessary:

In foo.php:

```
<?php
    // some php code here.
    require('foo.html');
?>
```

In foo.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
```

Comment: @luweiqi I suggest you try it yourself.

Comment: @luweiqi It's possible to `require()` html files.

Comment: Yup, I got mixed up, thanks for the clarification ;)

Comment: @C0dekid.php You can include, require, include_once, or require_once an HTML file (or PHP file or any file). The functions don't care about the file contents. The difference is how it handles files that do not exist. Include throws a warning. Require throws an error.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are looking for an MVC patter

M - Model
V - View
C - Controller.

The model feeds a view with that data it needs and the controller call the business logic to get the right view and data.

With that most php frameworks out there are mvc or can be. Those frameworks include:

laravel, symfony, codeigniter, etc.

If you do not want to tie yourself to a particular framework you could just a few libraries out there to create your own. I use:

Slim - for routing

PHP ActiveRecord - DB access

Twig - Template engine for the view.